# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function data()

Tags: php

Почему выдаёт ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function data() in
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\stell-team.ru\page\reg.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\OSPanel\domains\stell-team.ru\index.php(22): include() #1 {main}
>   thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\stell-team.ru\page\reg.php on line 11

Версия php 7

Проблема в функции data()
`$reg_data = data("d:m:Y");` , как это исправить.
Мне нужно сделать так чтобы у меня определялась дата на моем пк и добавлялась в бд (запрос уже есть просто не определяет дату и выдает ошибку, которая указана выше!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильное имя функции, не `data()` а `date()`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное вы спасли мне жизнь и нервы